# Pass an array into stored procedure and insert those values SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have to insert these values into a table:

```
ID   Col1   col2  date
1      10    5    getdate()
2      20    5    getdate()
3      30    5    getdate()
```

Column 1 comes in a string '10,20,30' and I am using function splintint to parse and get data

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitInts
(
   @List      VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN ( SELECT Item = CONVERT(INT, Item) FROM
      ( SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
        FROM ( SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>'
        + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
          ) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i) ) AS y
      WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
  );
GO
```

And in the stored procedure

```
SELECT @lenList = Count(Item) FROM dbo.SplitInts(@Col1List, ','); 
IF @lenList > 0

        WHILE @i <= @lenList
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @col1 = CONVERT(INT,Item) FROM dbo.SplitInts(@Col1List, ','); 


            INSERT
            INTO [dbo].[Table1]
            (
                [Col1],
                [Col2],
                [CreatedOn],
            )
            VALUES
            (
                @col1,
                @col2,
                getdate()
            )

            SET @i = @i+1
        END
```

But the issue is I see only last row gets inserted every time i.e., 30, 5 here. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ouch. You have a nice set based splitter but then you are still looping. That kind of defeats the purpose. Of course, the best approach by far would be to pass in a table valued parameter instead of a delimited list. Then you can simply use it like a table. You can read about them https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx and how you can use them here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by doing the following:

```
INSERT
   INTO [dbo].[Table1]
    (
      [Col1],
      [Col2],
      [CreatedOn],
    )
Select 
    Item As Col1
    ,@Col2
    ,GETDATE()
From 
dbo.SplitInts(@Col1List, ',');
```